# Circular Image Border in android

Tags: android, imageview

I changed the image to circular shape but I need a border around the circular image. The Border is not displayed for me.

This is my code

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap result = null;
    try {
        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

        int color = 0xff424242;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the good third party library for circular image view. You can also add border to rounded imageview.

https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 0):

You can use setStrokeWidth() method of paint. you can refer this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth(float))

Also if you want to give border to imageView then use below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="@dimen/two"
            android:left="@dimen/two"
            android:right="@dimen/two"
            android:top="@dimen/two" />

        <corners android:radius="@dimen/two_zero" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Now give this xml as background to Imageview.